# URL redirect malware

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, model-view-controller, malware

My ASP MVC web site effected from URL redirect malware recently.There are several web site hosted in IIS in azure server and only one web site opens unwanted popups and redirecting. I have checked same site within local IIS by hosting and it also gave the same result . This is not happening always but it happens suddenly.Any body has idea how I can figure out what is the reason and how I can prevent these issue ?

Comment: without specifics we can't give specific advice. But if the site is infected then you'll clearly need to restore a non-infected version from a backup (or re-deploy from the correct version of the source) and/or clean any data which is part of the problem, at some point. You may want to take a copy of the infected version and deploy it to a test environment for further investigation. Check file permissions, check for vulnerabilities for SQL injection, script injection etc which may have allow malicious content onto the site. Look at logs to look for suspicious requests, etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue occurs locally and also an Azure VM evidently not an Azure issue. As Adyson rightly mentioned “the site is infected and you need to restore a non-infected version from a backup or re-deploy from the correct version of the source.

In an IaaS deployment, you are still responsible for the management of the systems that you deploy, just like any other server or workstation in your environment. Patching, hardening, rights assignments, and any other activity related to the maintenance of your system are still your responsibility. For systems that are tightly integrated with your on-premises resources, you might want to use the same tools and procedures that you're using on-premises for things like antivirus, antimalware, patching, and backup.

Check the document Security best practices for IaaS workloads in Azure for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-iaas

IIS security: At the level of Internet Information Services (IIS), you set content permissions, authentication controls, and operator privileges. Refer Managing Web Server Security (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727096.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more details.